# Unable to convert SVG into a mesh

Tags: mesh, svg

I am trying to convert a simple logo from SVG into a blender mesh without any success.

My logo contains a simple shape and Text.

I converted the logo into SVG using both Inkscape and Adobe Illustrator. Both SVG files are imported fine into Blender. But neither can be converted into a mesh no matter how I tried.

I am very new to Blender. Can someone provide some guidance?

Jing

---

My SVG file can be downloaded here.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bUKh3SxEcaCMzHHVZctJgZxXJamNmA2A/view?usp=sharing

Thank you so much for your help.

Jing

Comment: could you please share your svg file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: "*But neither can be converted into a mesh*" Why not? What happens when you try?

Answer (score 1):

[image: SVG convert to mesh]
There isn't any problem with the SVG (you may just need to increase the size). I hope you know the convert to mesh option (invoked by pressing space bar in 3d view / object mode) to convert the SVG paths to a mesh.

Just in case you haven't done this, you need to select the imported object first.

[image: Select object]

Comment: I tried to hit Alt C or try to access it via the Object -> Convert To. But the option is totally grayed out for me. Do you have any idea what my problem is? Jing

Comment: You need to first selected the imported path. See the edit.

Comment: This is what I got.

Comment: This is what I got. https://youtu.be/z06t1VIli58

Comment: That's because both the objects are selected. Go to 'Select', then 'Deselect All' and then just select one object at a time by right clicking it.

Comment: @JingGu if this answered your question plese mark the answer as correct, so this question gets closed. If it didnt pleas keep explaining your problem

Comment: This answer should be accepted. It solved my issues. Why he never accepted an answer I have no idea. Kind of ungrateful.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to convert all the curves.

After importing the file from File -> Import -> SVG

As soon as you import the curve option is disable if Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

So just select an object and then press <kbd>A</kbd> twice to select all and then Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

[image]